# Troubleshooting Selenium Element Location Issue in Python on Twitter

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, twitter

I'm attempting to use Selenium in Python to log in to Twitter. However, I'm encountering difficulties when trying to locate an element by its class name. Specifically, I'm trying to find a div element with the class name L5Fo6c-sM5MNb. When I run my program, I receive the following error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55f63ef08e23 <unknown>
#1 0x55f63ec317a7 <unknown>
#2 0x55f63ec701d3 <unknown>
#3 0x55f63ec702c1 <unknown>
#4 0x55f63ecaba04 <unknown>
#5 0x55f63ec9103d <unknown>
#6 0x55f63eca9369 <unknown>
#7 0x55f63ec90de3 <unknown>
#8 0x55f63ec64a7b <unknown>
#9 0x55f63ec6581e <unknown>
#10 0x55f63eeca638 <unknown>
#11 0x55f63eece507 <unknown>
#12 0x55f63eed8c4c <unknown>
#13 0x55f63eecf136 <unknown>
#14 0x55f63ee9d9cf <unknown>
#15 0x55f63eef2b98 <unknown>
#16 0x55f63eef2d68 <unknown>
#17 0x55f63ef01cb3 <unknown>
#18 0x7f2cdaa8f18a <unknown>
```

Here's my source code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--lang=hr")
options.add_experimental_option(
    "excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"],
)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login")
main_page = driver.current_window_handle
login_page = main_page

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'L5Fo6c-sM5MNb'))
)
```

I've confirmed that the page loads within a time frame less than 10 seconds, so that doesn't seem to be the issue. Furthermore, `div` with that class name exists (Attachment I). What steps should I take to resolve this problem and successfully locate the element using Selenium?

[Attachemnt I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzLmn.png)